# DATABASE LINK Can't connect to remote database

Tags: sql, oracle, dblink

I am creating a two database A & B
A can connect to B with database link but the problem is that, B can't connect to A. User name and password are all the same in both A and B

With message Error : ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

SYS_PRIV on A is

```
CREATE SESSION
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK
CREATE DATABASE LINK
```

and SYS_PRIV on B is

```
CREATE SESSION
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK
CREATE DATABASE LINK
```

is there any other privileges that I should check ? because I can make link to B but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the database name as you use it in the database link is available in the tnsnames.ora on your Oracle server. Because that's what the error message says.

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

It cannot find the name you specified.

Comment: Thanks Rene... you mean TNSNAMES.ORA in A or in B ?? I am sorry im a newbie learning oracle

Comment: If you want B to connect to A it has to know about A. So the tnsnames.ora on B should contain A.

Comment: I checked the TNSNAMES.ORA and everyting seems fine.. where did i do wreong "?